# Truncate similar lines to discard difference in sorted file

Tags: bash, sorting

Lets assume I have a log file full of errors. but of just a handful of types.

```
com.company.exception.ExceptionOne: customer cart is empty for customerId: QWEDSA
com.company.exception.ExceptionOne: customer cart is empty for customerId: fdsadf
com.company.exception.ExceptionOne: customer cart is empty for customerId: ...
com.company.exception.ExceptionOne: customer cart is empty for customerId: ---
com.company.exception.ExceptionTWO: ITEM NOT FOUND on purchase: ---
com.company.exception.ExceptionTWO: ITEM NOT FOUND on purchase: ...
com.company.exception.ExceptionTWO: ITEM NOT FOUND on purchase: ---
com.company.exception.ExceptionTWO: unknown error.
com.company.exception.ExceptionTHREE: error found while requesting from service A {requestId: 1, ...}
com.company.exception.ExceptionTHREE: error found while requesting from service A {requestId: 2, ...}
```

Ideal output:

```
4 com.company.exception.ExceptionOne: customer cart is empty for customerId:
3 com.company.exception.ExceptionTWO: ITEM NOT FOUND on purchase:
2 com.company.exception.ExceptionTHREE: error found while requesting from service A {requestId: 
1 com.company.exception.ExceptionTWO: unknown error.
```

It'd be easy if similar lines were identical with `uniq -c | sort -bgr`

Comment: What is you definition of “similar” ? You can pre-process the file (send, Perl) to replace the non-important tokens, so the sort will be able to find them.

Comment: Good question. You probably don’t know the types of messages up front. So it should find patterns in a more flexible way. Might need more than 2 similar lines to find a good truncation point. Point is it should not be hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your sample log entries, you are lucky, all the fields you want to ignore are located after the second `:`.  You could therefore do:

```
cat log | cut -d':' -f1-2 | uniq -c | sort -bgr
```

Where `log` is the filename of your log file.  Replace to match your reality.

Comment: That’s my bad for the sample I gave. I can’t expect real log files to present that pattern. Only to have same errors for different requests, i.e. slightly different messages.

Comment: Then we cannot provide real life responses without a real life sample of data lines.  The idea remains however, find a pattern, remove what you do not want to keep, sort after.  `awk` would be nice for this as you can apply different cutting methods to different line patterns.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll look into that. Can’t share real logs, sorry. Should have made more complex example but that’s all I could have done better. I imagined we could sort lines by Levenshtein distance and then find 1st diff with a caterpillar or something (ignoring timestamps)

Comment: Yes something like "sort lines that are similar by 80% of content".  It's getting close to machine learning...  But most logs I see have a somewhat limited number of patterns that you can exploit.